# Joomla multi domain site - cache

Tags: caching, joomla

I have a Joomla site which primary domain is www.domain.com
Then there are other domains which point to the same joomla site (www.2nd-domain.com, www.3rd-domain.com, etc...).

All good, except for the caching.
When cache is cleared, whichever domain's request comes first, the domain is written in the cache for the resource loading and as I am using SSL, this resources are then blocked when visiting the site from other domains.

I know what the problem is and it is ok that the resources from other sites are blocked - what i would like to know is how to solve this so that caching would properly work for all of the domains. Maybe some internal rewrites of the daomin names, seperate caching per domain, some other...

I have googled a bit, but no such question/answer poped out.
This is pretty common scenario for big sites with many domains, so there must be a way i am not aware of.

Any suggestions, tips or links to resources would be appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use tool like Redis, there is a nice tutorial at this [link](https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/how-to-install-and-enable-redis-cache-in-joomla/)

Comment: Thx for the tip. I know Redis from Rails development and was already considering it, but i don't see hot it would help me with multi-domain setup. I think the problem would be practiacally the same as this is only moving cache from file to Redis. Or is it inteligent enough "out of the box" (probably Joomla)

Comment: you can setup a single redis server, and link all your site to that cache via redis i hope this will work for you. beside that this is also a nice article to have joomla over LB https://severalnines.com/blog/how-scale-joomla-multiple-servers